# Slow CRUD @RelationshipEntity in SDN 4.0

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j-4

I try to save properties on a RelathionEntity

As i read here

[How to CRUD @RelationshipEntity in SDN 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621464/how-to-crud-relationshipentity-in-sdn-4-0/32628148#32628148)

this is possible saving one of the start/end node, but i notice that this is extreme slow instead of saving a node with deth 0 (saving a node with depth 0 takes about 2ms, saving a node with depth 1 takes about 1000ms). The node that I'm trying to save has only 4 relationships

I've tried also session.save(...) (org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session) on an object annotated as @RelationshipEntity, but it does nothing

I use spring-data-neo4j 4.0.0.RELEASE and Neo4j 2.2.5

Follow the code for entities and relationships:

```
@NodeEntity
public class EntityA{
   @GraphId
   private Long             nodeId;
   private String               propertyA;
   @Relationship(type = "RelationshipAB", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
   private Set<RelationshipAB>  entitiesB   = new HashSet<RelationshipAB>();
}

@NodeEntity
public class EntityB{
   @GraphId
   private Long nodeId;
   private String   propertyB;
}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "RelationshipAB")
public class RelationshipAB{
   @GraphId
   private Long nodeId;
   @StartNode
   private EntityA  entityA;
   @EndNode
   private EntityB  entityB;
   @Property
   private String   propertyAB;
 }
```

Follow a simple test case for checking the performace:

```
    EntityA entityA = new EntityA();
    entityA.setPropertyA("propertyA");
    entityARepository.save(entityA);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        EntityB entityB = new EntityB();
        entityB.setPropertyB("propertyB-" + i);
        entityBRepository.save(entityB);

        RelationshipAB rel = new RelationshipAB();
        rel.setEntityA(entityA);
        rel.setEntityB(entityB);
        rel.setPropertyAB("propertyAB-" + i);

        entityA.getEntitiesB().add(rel);

        Date startDate = new Date();
        entityARepository.save(entityA, 1);
        Date endDate = new Date();
        System.out.println("Time for adding " + (i + 1) + " node: " + (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) + " ms");
    }

    Iterator<RelationshipAB> iter = entityA.getEntitiesB().iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        iter.next();
    }
    iter.next().setPropertyAB("newProperty1");
    Date startDate = new Date();
    entityARepository.save(entityA, 1);
    Date endData = new Date();
    System.out.println("Time for cahnge the first relationship property: " + (endData.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) + " ms");

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        iter.next();
    }
    iter.next().setPropertyAB("newProperty2");
    startDate = new Date();
    entityARepository.save(entityA, 1);
    endData = new Date();
    System.out.println("Time for cahnge the second relationship property: " + (endData.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) + " ms");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        iter.next();
    }
    iter.next().setPropertyAB("newProperty3");
    startDate = new Date();
    entityARepository.save(entityA, 1);
    endData = new Date();
    System.out.println("Time for cahnge the third relationship property: " + (endData.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) + " ms");
```

The adding nodes takes less than 100ms, the first update (the save after setPropertyAB("newProperty1")) takes about 1s, the next update takes about 4s and the last one about 7s

Comment: Memory and/or network problems are the most likely reasons for the performance problems you are experiencing.

Please could you confirm your network connection to your neo4j instance is performant (try some cypher queries from the browser for example), and also that you aren't running out of memory either in the server, or in your application code.

Comment: We have no network/memory issues. I want only change a property in a relationship, in the previous version I did it saving the RelationshipEntity (it took few ms), with the new version I have to save one of the node in the relationship, and it takes at least 1000ms. Is there any other method to save the properties of a relationship?

Comment: It might be helpful for you to add a snippet of code that does what you're trying to do -- and also please indicate what measurement method are you using that tells you that this particular save (and no other part of your software stack) is what's responsible for the slowness.

Comment: Sometimes it's difficult to track these sorts of things down, and modern stacks have a lot of complexity in them, make sure to isolate for absolute sure that where you think the slowdown is, is in fact where it is before proceeding.

Comment: I added a snippet of code on the original post. Thank you

Comment: The entity A then has 100 rels, not 4? It might be better to add them to entitiy B instead and save that.

Comment: Your test code runs in < 50ms when run here. Thats more than 2 orders of magnitude faster than the worst case scenario you reported. You almost certainly have a problem elsewhere in your stack or the control code that is running these tests that is causing this slowdown.

Comment: Thank you Michael, your tip makes the test much more faster. However, if the entity B itself is related to other nodes, the execution time is still slow. As Vince said, maybe the problem is in the environment: if I execute the same test on an empty DB, the same updates take 200ms each one. The environment where I notice the slowness has 415'854 nodes and 1'046'020 relationship (the types of nodes and relationship are different than I used for the test). Thank you for your support

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample database? Or is it enough to run the test just a few thousand times to get a similar structure?

Comment: You can download my db at this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uoh1tbmlmzhxxjg/graph.db.tar.gz?dl=0 and the test case at this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/huqatkka6e66mre/neo4j.performance.test.zip?dl=0 (the test is TestPerformance2). I created a structure where every EntityA has 10 relationships with EntityB and every EntityB has 10 relationships with EntityC. After a change, if I save the EntityA node, the update is slow, but if I save the EntityB node (even if I performed a load on the EntityB so all its relationships are loaded), the update is fast. Thank for your support.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested from Michael Hunger, this performance problems are fixed in version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Until 1.1.3 is released, you'll need to add a dependency to the snapshots repository:

```
<repository>
    <id>neo4j-snapshots</id>
    <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

We tested it with our solution.